# What is the definition of velocity field of a fluid if not the velocity of the molecules of that fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity

In the page 74 of Batchelor's fluid mechanics book, it is given that

> Differentiation following the motion of the fluid It will be evident that in a steady flow field a material element of fluid may nevertheless experience acceleration through moving to a position where $\mathbf{u}$ has a different value. The derivative $\partial \mathbf{u} / \partial t$ is not the acceleration of an element at position $x$ at time $t,$ because the element is at that position only instantaneously. The correct expression for the acceleration of a material element may be found by noting that an element at position $x$ at time $t$ is at position $x+\mathbf{u} \delta t$ at time $t+\delta t,$ and that the change in its velocity in the small interval $\delta t$ is
> $$
> \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u} \delta t, t+\delta t)-\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}, t), \quad=\delta t\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}\right)+O\left(\delta t^{2}\right)
> $$

Before reading this paragraph, I thought $\vec{u}(\vec r, t)$, namely velocity at a specified time and position in space, refers to the velocity of the molecules of the fluid at $\vec r$, but apparently, this is not the case.

Then, what is the exact definition of $\vec u$, the velocity field of a fluid? How do you physically measure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single velocity field for the fluid at a given time instant, but that paragraph is trying to describe how the *acceleration* defined as the partial derivative $\partial \vec{u}/\partial t$ is subtly different.

What they are trying to describe is that there are two different reference frames used in discussing fluid mechanics. The first reference frame is called an *Eulerian* reference frame, and in this frame you describe the fluid as it moves through fixed locations of space. In other words, you act as a stationary observer and formulate the equations for the motion of the fluid moving past each spatial position with time.

In contrast, the second reference frame is called a *Lagrangian* reference frame, and this is the reference frame used if you imagine a tiny packet of fluid and you formulate the governing equations for how that tiny packet of fluid moves along its trajectory. In other words, you are writing the equations for the motion of a fluid "particle" or "parcel" or "packet" as it moves through space and time.

That paragraph is describing how the acceleration is different in these two different frames, and how they relate. The acceleration in the Eulerian frame is $\partial \vec{u} /\partial t$ and it will tell you how the velocity is changing at every *stationary* spatial location.

If you were instead interested in the acceleration of a particular fluid packet, then you want the use the Lagrangian reference frame and follow the fluid packet of interest. The acceleration of a single fluid packet along its trajectory is given by the expression provided in your paragraph.

*Acceleration in Eulerian reference frame*: $$\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t}$$

*Acceleration in Lagrangian reference frame*:

$$\frac{d \vec{u}}{dt}, \frac{D \vec{u}}{Dt}$$

can be related to the Eulerian frame via $$\frac{D \vec{u}}{Dt} = \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} + \vec{u} \cdot \nabla \vec{u}$$

The derivative in the Lagrangian frame is also often called the ["Substantial" or "Material" derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative).

---

As an aside, when discussing continuum mechanics, we can't really discuss molecules. The behavior of a continuum is described by equations when we average away all the molecular motion and we're left with some average of how all the molecules within a region behave. Although we often talk about "fluid particles" when discussing continuum motion of fluids, we're really just talking about "an infinitesimal volume of fluid that still contains an infinite amount of molecules such that it can be described as a continuum."

So the velocity field you get from the Navier Stokes equations is the velocity of the bulk motion of the fluid molecules and it is not the motion of any particular molecule in general. It's a minor point that isn't important here, but there is a difference between molecular motion and continuum motion that does become important under some flow regimes.

Comment: what you are saying contradicts with what the book says after the paragraph:

"The acceleration is of course a quantity which can be expressed very simply in the Lagrangian type of specification of the flow field; if $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of a certain fluid element, the acceleration of the element is $\partial \mathbf{v} / \partial t .$"

Comment: in particular, this line: "That paragraph is describing how the acceleration is different in these two different frames, and how they relate. The acceleration in the Eulerian frame is ∂⃗/∂ and it will tell you how the velocity is changing at every stationary spatial location."

Comment: @onurcanbkts I don't have the book, but it seems like they are just using different notation than I did here. They are saying that $\partial \vec{v} /\partial t = \partial \vec{u} /\partial t + \vec{u} \cdot \nabla \vec{u} = D \vec{u} / Dt$. There's a few different notation sets out there, I used the one I am most familiar with.

Comment: no, $\vec v$ means the velocity in the Lagragian frame, not the material derivative. When they use the material derivative, they explicitly use $D / Dt$ notation.

Comment: @onurcanbkts Without more context, I can't really say what is tripping you up exactly. But I guess there's one other way to look at it, which is that in an Eulerian frame you have a velocity $\vec{u}(\vec{x},t)$ at every point in space at a given time, and in a Lagrangian frame, you have the *position* of a fluid particle at a point in time, $\vec{X}(\vec{x}_0, t)$ where $\vec{x}_0$ is the starting position of the fluid packet. Then you could have a Lagrangian velocity $\vec{v} = \partial \vec{X} / \partial t$.

Comment: Which can then be used to come up with a Lagrangian acceleration $\partial \vec{v}/\partial t$. The two velocities should be related by $\vec{v} = \vec{u}(\vec{X}(\vec{x}_0,t),t)$. In words, the Lagrangian velocity is the Eulerian velocity at the current position of the fluid parcel and so the two fields are the same, but have a different acceleration.

Comment: I think the real answer to the question is just what you have described  "As an side...". In my opinion, the first part of your answer is related to a different question.